# Serverless - How to create a standalone customer managed policy through serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

Currently my serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
service: aaaaa

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: mydev

resources:
  Resources:
    MyManagedPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties: 
        Description: This is my custom managed policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: s3:GetObject
              Resource: '*'
```

When I run "**sls deploy**" command, I am getting following error:

**Error:**

An error occurred: MyManagedPolicy - Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: a20aa12c-fbaf-4301-bd20-b0148426f633).

Can you please point out the syntax error? I am new to serverless so not able to understand.

If possible please suggest the working serverless.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyManagedPolicy` policy is **correct**. There is nothing wrong with its syntax, yaml nor the `PolicyDocument`.

**To verify it**, I created my own template with your  `MyManagedPolicy` and it deployed without any issues.

However, upon tests with serverless, I can confirm that this does not work with the same issue as OP reported.

Upon further investigation it was identified that the serverless **incorrectly** specifies `Version: 2012-10-17` as:

```
 "Version": "2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"
```

The **solution was to use date in quotes**:

```
Version: "2012-10-17"
```

Comment: can you please give it a try using serverless? I am running "sls deploy" command to create this managed policy. In my case it is failing. Any idea about why i am getting this error through serverless?

Comment: @Jatin You are correct. I will update the answer with the cause and solution.

Comment: thank you. It is working after using quotes for version.

Comment: @Jatin No problem. Wonder if this is a `serverless`  bug or not?

Comment: Can you tell me where did you notice version is converted to "Version": "2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"??? I am not able to locate the place where i can also see the same error.

Comment: @Jatin Serverless will create an S3 bucket where the CFN template it generates will be placed for the deployment. I inspected the template generated in S3.